# UIbutton in 2nd Cell in UICollectionView doesn't respond

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

In my UICollectionView, the UIButtons in my first UICollectionViewCell work fine while the uibuttons in my second UICollectionViewCell do not work.

If it's relevant, I have only two cells and both cells are loaded initially because both cells are visible. ~10 pixels of the second CollectionViewcell is visible when the first UICollectionViewCell is in focus.

Comment: How do you connect the UIControlEventTouchUpInside event to the corresponding action?

Comment: I'm using an IBOutlet